# Wrong Days Between Dates for Month of March

Tags: objective-c

I have a very interesting problem: When calculating the number of days between two dates, my calculator gives the wrong results **for the month of March only**. I have two text fields, one for each date. If I enter 3/7/12 in date1, and 3/13/12 in date2, the result is 7, which is correct (I am counting the first day as well). But when I enter date1 = 3/7/12 and date2 = 3/14/12, the result is still 7, but it should be 8. Likewise, if I enter date1 = 3/7/12 and date2 = 3/23/12, the result should be 17, but it is 16. If I change the month to April so that date1 = 4/7/12 and date2 = 4/23/12, the result is 17. Every month is working as intended, only the month of March is giving me wrong results. Does anyone have any idea what I am missing? Is this a timezone problem? How do I fix it? Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; 
    NSDate *startdate1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString: date1.text]; 

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate *enddate2 = [dateFormatter2 dateFromString: date2.text];

    int start1 = [startdate1 timeIntervalSince1970];
    int end2 = [enddate2 timeIntervalSince1970];
    double difference12 = end2-start1;
    int days12;

    days12 =(int)((double)difference12/(3600.0*24.00)+1);

    result12.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", days12]
```

Comment: In the USA, daylight saving time was March 11th in 2012 (it is March 10th in 2013). Assuming you are in the USA, this is probably throwing off the calculation when the two dates straddle March 11th (or 10th).

Answer (score 3):

If you use NSCalendar, you won't need to deal with Daylight Savings Time calculation.

```
int days = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                    fromDate:startDate1
                      toDate:endDate2
                     options:0] day] + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most like this is a daylight savings issue (March 11th, 2012). Set the date formatters' timezones to:

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To add to others, please do not rely on number of seconds in a day being 86400 all the time, it won't. Be sure to watch Session 211 Performing Calendar Calculations from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).

Answer (score 0):

You can think of NSDate as a point in time. If you want to calculate number of days between two dates, this is a calendar issue and there are more than one calendars (like the Mayan calendar).

What you need is NSDateComponents:

```
NSDate *dateToday = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateBComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateBComponent setDay:-10];  
NSDate *date10DaysAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateBComponent
                                                                         toDate:dateToday
                                                                        options:0];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                 fromDate:date10DaysAgo
                                                   toDate:dateToday
                                                  options:0];

NSLog(@"Difference: %d", components.day);
```